# Chrome on Ubuntu 19.10 is blocking cookies and third-party cookies for all websites

Tags: firefox, google-chrome

My laptop is running Ubuntu 19.10 as the only OS.

On the laptop Chrome is blocking cookies and third-party cookies for all websites. The small symbol with the red x lets me choose from "allow www... to set cookies" and "continue blocking cookies" but neither one works, i.e. allowing the website to set cookies doesn't actually let it set cookies.

I am posting here because using Chrome on my Android tablet does not have this problem with the exact same websites but FireFox on Ubuntu 19.10 does, so it seems to be an OS problem.

```
> $ google-chrome --version Google Chrome 79.0.3945.117
> 
> $ dpkg -l | grep google-chrome ii  google-chrome-stable  
> 79.0.3945.117-1   amd64    The web browser from Google
```

Comment: What is your Google Chrome version? How did you installed it? Please add output of `google-chrome --version` and `dpkg -l | grep google-chrome` to the question.

Comment: @N0rbert I have been using Chrome on Unbuntu for many years now. I update from the website when Chrome says an update is available.I have added your requests to the OP. Thanks for the Bemühung!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to visit the Settings of Google Chrome - `chrome://settings/content/cookies`.

Here on my Ubuntu 16.04.6 LTS with the same Google Chrome version I have allowed cookies:

> [image: cookies allowed]

but newer versions [will block third-party cookies in 2 years](https://blog.chromium.org/2020/01/building-more-private-web-path-towards.html).

If I set first slider to *Block* and third to *Block third-party cookies* I get the special icon [image: Cookies blocked] in the address-bar.

Comment: Ok, following your advice I can now watch the advertisements on ITV Hub but still get the same warning before the program starts.

Comment: The cookie warning has gone after following your advice. I still cannot stream some sites though, but I think this might be a widevine problem..